# Prevent "GUI Freezing" While Checking a File Exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5, qthread

I'm trying to build a file listener app in pyqt5. My code works as I want, but I want to improve it.

There is a simple button `Listen`. When I click it, it opens a notepad and it starts to always listen until a `a.txt` file exists. After exist, a new button `Start` exists, old button is removed.

My problem is; my GUI is freezing while it is listening the `a.txt` file **even I use `threading`**. Am I using wrong? Can you fix my code?

My main code;

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys
import os

class ListenWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListenWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Listen")

        self.button_listen = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Listen', self)
        font1 = self.button_listen.font()
        font1.setPointSize(10)
        self.button_listen.setFont(font1)
        self.button_listen.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.button_listen.clicked.connect(self.startToListen)

        self.v_box1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_box1.addWidget(self.button_listen)

        self.h_box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_box1.addLayout(self.h_box1)

    def abc(self):
        while not os.path.exists('C:/Users/Wicaledon/PycharmProjects/myproject/a.txt'):
            pass

        if os.path.isfile('C:/Users/Wicaledon/PycharmProjects/myproject/a.txt'):
            self.button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start', self)
            font2 = self.button_start.font()
            font2.setPointSize(10)
            self.button_start.setFont(font2)
            self.button_start.setFixedSize(200, 50)
            self.h_box1.addWidget(self.button_start, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        else:
            raise ValueError("%s isn't a file!" % 'C:/Users/Wicaledon/PycharmProjects/myproject/a.txt')
        self.v_box1.removeWidget(self.button_listen)

    def startToListen(self):
        def thread_function(my_text):
            import subprocess
            import os
            FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
            args = my_text
            subprocess.call(args, stdout=FNULL, stderr=FNULL, shell=True)
            # os.system(my_text)
            return
        import threading
        my_text = "notepad"
        x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function,args=(my_text,))
        x.start()
        y = threading.Thread(target=ListenWindow.abc(self))
        y.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ListenWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Login')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My code for creating `a.txt`;

```
f=open("a.txt", "w+")
f.write("delete_me")
f.close()
```

Comment: You need to use Qt threads instead of Python threads.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I tried to edit my code for QThread but I couldn't. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good thing to use that simple while approach to check if a file exists, because it consumes a lot of CPU resources unnecessarily.
Also, using any kind of loop (while/for or recursive function calls) is a bad idea when dealing with an UI: as you've already seen, it blocks the interface; while the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59837237/2001654) proposed by abhilb might seem to work, it just makes the UI responsive, but will keep the CPU spiking anyway, even after the program is closed and the file has not been created.

PyQt already has a file listener, [QFileSystemWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html), and external systems should avoided with Qt that functionality has already provided by it, this counts not only for the file watcher, but also for threading.

Another important aspect to remember is that Qt has its own event loop, and it's not a good idea to use python's threads to interact with it (as a matter of fact, *every* UI interaction has to be done in the main thread, even when using Qt's threads).

If you really want to do a basic file listener (eg, for study purposes), you should at least add a waiter within the cycle, and that cycle *has* to be in another thread, otherwise the GUI will be blocked anyway.

The following is an implementation completely based on Qt, based on your code.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

fileToWatch = 'C:/Users/Wicaledon/PycharmProjects/myproject/a.txt'
editorProgram = 'notepad'

class ListenWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ListenWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Listen")

        self.button_listen = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Listen', self)
        font1 = self.button_listen.font()
        font1.setPointSize(10)
        self.button_listen.setFont(font1)
        self.button_listen.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.button_listen.clicked.connect(self.startToListen)

        self.v_box1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.v_box1.addWidget(self.button_listen)

        # no parent with an already existing layout should be set for a new
        # layout; in this case, the current widget already has the v_box1 layout
        # set, therefore the new h_box1 layout should have no argument
        self.h_box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.v_box1.addLayout(self.h_box1)

        self.listener = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(self)
        self.listener.directoryChanged.connect(self.checkFile)

    def startToListen(self):
        fileInfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(fileToWatch)
        if fileInfo.exists():
            self.createStart()
            return
        elif fileInfo.absolutePath() not in self.listener.directories():
            self.listener.addPath(fileInfo.absolutePath())

        # create an empty file so that there's no error when trying to open
        # it in the editor
        emptyFile = QtCore.QFile(fileToWatch)
        emptyFile.open(emptyFile.WriteOnly)
        emptyFile.close()

        process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        process.start(editorProgram, [fileToWatch])

        # optional: disable the interface until the program has quit
        self.setEnabled(False)
        process.finished.connect(lambda: self.setEnabled(True))

    def checkFile(self, path):
        fileInfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(fileToWatch)
        if fileInfo.exists():
            if self.h_box1:
                # the layout already contains the start button, ignore
                return
            else:
                self.createStart()
        else:
            # file has been [re]moved/renamed, maybe do something here...
            pass

    def createStart(self):
        self.button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start', self)
        font2 = self.button_start.font()
        font2.setPointSize(10)
        self.button_start.setFont(font2)
        self.button_start.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.h_box1.addWidget(self.button_start, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ListenWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Login')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: so much thanks for fixing include all my writing style. but when there is no `a.txt` and click `Listen`, it shows a popup window and says "The file cannot be found. Do you want to create a new one?", and I click "No". I don't want to see this popup. Also, after click "No", and after creating `a.txt` with script, the `Start` button exists but both buttons are not clickable. I tried to add `self.button_start.setEnabled(True)` inside `createStart` function but doesn't work. can you help me ?

Comment: @Wicaledon that is probably a popup from notepad (or windows), and I cannot help you with it as I'm on Linux, but if that's the case I doubt you can do anything (unless some obscure command line option exists preventing the popup to appear). About the disabled buttons, as explained in the comment that's just optional (read the code and try to understand it), and it assumes that the notepad program is run and correctly closed afterwards. If you don't close the notepad (which emits the `finished` signal), the buttons will stay disabled. If you are not interested in that, just remove that part.

Comment: as you said I'm done the blocking of the buttons with deleting the optional 2 line, thank you so much. For the popup, I will try more. Thank you. EDIT: I changed `process.start(editorProgram, [fileToWatch])` to `process.start(editorProgram)` and works as I want

Comment: @Wicaledon I added the cretion of an empty file before launching the editor process to avoid the error message. See the modification.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `while` loop in your `abc` function to

```py
        while not os.path.exists('b.txt'):
            QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            pass
```

Comment: This is not a very good solution, as it will continuously cycle the while loop, and unnecessarily consuming CPU resources in the meantime. Moreover, in the case the file is not created, that loop will continue to cycle even after closing the program.